Configurar Horas com os dois primeiros digitos "vazios" no Pandas
tenho uma base de dados com uma coluna de Horas(THTIME), que contem horas com os dois primeiros dígitos em branco Ex: 3855 onde seria 00:38:55. preciso de uma ajuda para configurar esse horário para que reconheça os valores em branco como as zero horas.
Entrada: 3855
Saida: 03:08:55
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Mov Prod.xlsx")

df["THTIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["THTIME"], format='%H%M%S').dt.time

print(df)


Sua problema pode possuir outras soluções, mas da forma como está formulada sua pergunta existem vários caminhos a seguir. Seria bom ter uma amostra de teste da planilha Mov Prod.xlsx pois dependendo de como os dados salvos seu problema pode ser solucionado na leitura dos dados. Se não for possível solucionar o problema na leitura, ainda precisamos saber se todos os dados estão com as horas com dois dígitos em branco ou se também existem horários com o formato correto ou se existem valores com horários com apenas um dígitos em branco?

Transforme a coluna THTIME para string e adicione zeros na frente dos valores.
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({"THTIME": [3855, 4040]})

>>>df
   THTIME
0    3855
1    4040


>>>pd.to_datetime(df["THTIME"].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time

0    00:38:55
1    00:40:40
Name: THTIME, dtype: object

Basta atribuir à coluna inicial
>>>df["THTIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df["THTIME"].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time


Para aqueles que votaram negativo, poderiam indicar o motivo para que eu possa melhorar esta resposta,?
